# Play framework: [IllegalStateException: No value] when using foreign key in a form

Tags: exception, playframework-2.0, foreign-keys

I'm starting with the play framework and have run into the following issue.

Situation: My app has two tables, Trainers and Trainings (1:n).

My Models:
Trainer.java

```
@Entity
public class Trainer extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  @Constraints.Required
  public String trainerShortcut;
  @Constraints.Required
  public String firstName;
  @Constraints.Required
  public String lastName;
  @Constraints.Required
  public String email;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public List<Training> trainings;
  ...
```

Training.java

```
 @Entity
 public class Training extends Model {
   @Id
   public Long id;
   public String shortcut;
   public String name;
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="owner_id")
   public Trainer owner;
   public String description;
   ...
```

I've also generated the getters and setters in Eclipse.

My Controller:

```
public static Result addTraining() {
    Training training = Form.form(Training.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    training.save();
    return ok();
}
```

The situation: I have a simple form for adding a training, this form includes an "owner" input which contains a trainer id.

If I use the Eclipse-generated setter "setowner", I get the following execution exception (despite having a trainer with the given ID in the DB):

> [IllegalStateException: No value]

The line

> Training training = Form.form(Training.class).bindFromRequest().get(); 
>   is referenced

If I delete the Eclipse-generated setter, the "owner_id" field in the training table is NULL afterwards.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post it clearly indicates that your `owner` property in `Training.java` referring `Trainer` model expects `Trainer` object but it getting only `Trainer's id` which is supplied by the user as `owner` input, that's the source for the problem.

To resolve this issue you need to use [custom DataBinder](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaForms) which is explained at the end of the link.

Before binding the form, you need to register with `custom DataBinder`that will take care of converting `id` to `Trainer`

```java
public static Result validate(){
    Formatters.register(Trainer.class, new Formatters.SimpleFormatter<Trainer>(){
        @Override
        public Trainer parse(String input, Locale arg1) throws ParseException {
            Trainer trainer = Trainer.find.byId(new Long(input));
            return trainer;
        }

        @Override
        public String print(Trainer trainer, Locale arg1) {
            return trainer.id.toString();
        }
    });

    Training training = Form.form(Training.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    training.save();
    return ok();
}
```

Comment: I solved that also just a while ago by renaming the form input from "owner" to "owner.id" but your solution works as well!
I just had to use "Ebean.find(Trainer.class, input)" instead of Trainer.find.byId which is because of using Ebean I guess?